# Import, edit and Export saved SVG files

Tags: android, svg, androiddesignsupport, svg-filters, androidsvg

I am having a requirement where I have to generate a single svg file from various svg file like shapes into the canvas in android platform like making a image. And above that after saving that svg file I can also re-import that svg file and can undo/redo the changes done previously as well as making adding new stuff and saving the new svg file.

I am not much aware regarding importing and reusing the svg file after once it is saved and redo/undo or edit the previous changes step by step according to the layers in svg file and additionally making new changes into it.

I had R&D in figuring out the way but could not find any helpful solution. It would be great help if anyone can suggest me convenient ways to do that so.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want the app to merge svg files?

Comment: @LonelyCpp Yes to create image as SVG and re-import and make editing in the same file. Almost similar concept like illustrator for android platform.